# Dynamic validation list - data from other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have one worksheet where in a specified range should be validation list. This list is token from another worksheet (column A, from row 2 to last not-empty row). But it doesn't work and I can't figured why.

My code:

```
Set wsResourcesProjects = Sheets("ResourcesProjects")
Set wsProjects = Sheets("Projects")


With wsProjects.rGeneralFTERange.Offset(0, 3).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=ResourcesProjects!" & wsResourcesProjects.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

And in range rGeneralFTERange validation list is not appear. But when I change this part:

```
wsResourcesProjects.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Address
```

on

```
"A2:A10"
```

then it's works. But it's not good for me, because data in column "A" are dynamic.

Comment: If the validation list exists in another workbook, it will work if the source workbook is also opened else it wont work.

Comment: It is in the same workbook, just in another worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `Formula1:="=ResourcesProjects!"` exclimation **!** symbol might have created the problem, hope you have already created the named ranges :)

FYR [named ranges](http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/automating-data-validation-lists-in-excel)

```css
Sub validation()
    'Select your range
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.validation
        .Delete
        'Month_Val is the namedrange name
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Month_Val"
       
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I just solved the problem with this code: Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""'ResourcesProjects'!" & wsResourcesProjects.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Address & """)"

Comment: Oh, now I did it in your way. It works excelent. Didn't know it can be so easy. Thanks!